# How to resolve processing state in jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am developing a large scale application where i have to load a lot of data into one page so I am using jQuery Datatable with server-side pagination in an Angluar project.
The problem is that the table always keeps in processing state and does not load the data but the data shows up correctly after the ajax call but it does not show in the table.

here's the full controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var host = "http://localhost/";
    var table;
    angular.module('app')
    .controller('wfCtrl', wfCtrl);
    function wfCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {
        $scope.selanguage = "FR";
        $('#table-container').hide();
        $("#loader").append(" <img class='loader' width='50' src='./plugins/datatables/images/loader.gif'></img>")
        table = $('#data').DataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    url: host + 'api/workflow/' + $scope.selanguage,
                    type: "get", // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#loader").hide();
                        $('#table-container').show();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        $("#error").append("<p align=center class='loader' style='color:red'> No data found </p>")
                        $("#loader").hide();
                        $('#error').show();
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },
                "columns": [{
                        "className": 'details-control',
                        "orderable": false,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    }, {
                        "data": "worcode"
                    }, {
                        "data": "worstatus"
                    }, {
                        "data": "worlabel"
                    }, {
                        "data": "wordescription"
                    }, {
                        "orderable": false,
                        "defaultContent": "<div class='btn-group'>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success addstaaa' title='add a step' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-addst'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></button>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='edit workflow'></i></button>" +
                        "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' title='delete workflow'><i class='fa fa-trash' ></i></button>" +
                        "</div>"
                    }
                ],
                "start": 0,
                "length": 5
            });
    }
})();
```

here's the content of the data

```
{"draw":1,"data":[{"worcode":"AAA","wordest":"AVDOSS","worstatus":"ACTIF","worheight":0,"lancode" :"FR","worlabel":"Step","wordescription":"Step"},    {"worcode":"ABB","wordest":"AVDOSS","worstatus":"ACTIF","worheight":0,"lancode" :"EN","worlabel":"Monde","wordescription":"Monde"}],"recordsTotal":23,"recordsFiltered":23}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTables ajax docs (https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) say that you can not supply success and error properties for the ajax option, they are used internally and by supplying them you are preventing it from processing the ajax response. Remove these and DataTables can do its thing with the response.

If you need to do additional processing before/after datatables makes an ajax call you can hook into events, take a look at - https://datatables.net/reference/event/

Comment: i removed them but what is their equivalent events ? because i need to do some action in fail or success

Comment: I just readded the error properties for the onfail action and i added the initComplete properties  for the datatable in case of success , thanks for the answer

Comment: Take a look at the xhr event https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr . It is fired for success and failure and you can inspect the response. initComplete is fine if you're only loading data once as it occurs only when creating the initialising the datatable, if you call ajax.reload() at any point then initComplete or the init event will not give you the desired result. the xhr event is specifically for ajax calls.